# auth.uid is not getting the right UID in Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm working on an android project where users will be able to add a POJO to their own node in Firebase but only if the user has admin privileges.

In my Firebase database, I have the rules set up like this

```
"userAddedCars":{
  "$uid":{
    ".read" : "$uid == auth.uid",
    ".write" : "$uid == auth.uid && root.child('users').child(auth.uid).child('admin').val() == true"
      }
}
```

**A typical user node looks like this:**

```
root{
  "users"{
    "0MFmZkhIPAP4ccrdfY5F4uiCrNB3" : {
      "admin" : true,
      "email" : "pkj@bjj.com"
    }
  }
}
```

I have tested with the rule `$uid == auth.uid` and it works as intended i.e. *only able to write into their personal node*. However when paired with this rule `root.child('users').child(auth.uid).child('admin').val() == true` it seems as if `auth.uid` doesn't get the correct UID because it doesn't work as intended, although if I hard code the UID it starts working again.

I am not sure why `auth.uid` works some of the times but not always.

**Code used to add POJOS**

```
mRef = mRef.child("userAddedCars").child(UID);
mRef.child("car1").setValue(nCar);
```

Comment: You rules look correct to me.  I did a few quick tests using the simulator in the Firebase Console and got the results I expected.  I'd recommend you do more testing using the simulator.  It uses the actual data in your database and allows you to enter the auth.uid, making it a very convenient and effective way to quickly test your rules.

Comment: How do you get UID in client? Did you already use `String UID = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();`? Which firebase version did you use?

Answer (score 1):

Its a bit unclear on what you are trying to accomplish from the question so here is my assumption and the accompanying solution

**Assumption 1:**

You have set of Users who are either admins or not and they each have a set of used cars that are privately listed. While a user can see all the cars that are added to his/her private userAddedCars list they can only Add/Update/Modify them if they have admin privileges enabled.

PS: user is always authenticated

***Solution***

Your current rule set is right and it will work.

`auth.uid` is the UID of the currently authenticated user on the client device and in-relation to the above example data-set you will be able to execute your `setValue` code successfully if your login UID has admin property set to true under users node just like user `0MFmZkhIPAP4ccrdfY5F4uiCrNB3`.

if this is where you are failing you would have to elaborate on the situation with where its working and where its not working and the data-sets used to debug the issue further.

**Assumption 2:**

You have set of Users who can be sometimes admins although all of them have a set of used cars that are privately listed. While a user can see and edit all the cars that are added to his/her private userAddedCars list, but if user is admin then he can Add/Update/Modify cars for other users as well...

PS: user is always authenticated

***Solution***

Use the below rule set

```
{
    "rules": {
        "userAddedCars": {
            "$uid": {
                ".read": "$uid == auth.uid",
                ".write": "$uid == auth.uid || root.child('users').child(auth.uid).child('admin').val() == true"
            }
        }
    }
}
```